# Can URLConnection be used to get html by Id

Tags: java, javascript, html, urlconnection

I am looking to retrieve the html of a webpage using `URLConnection` but **I need only the element with some specific id.**
Is there any way to do so like we do using javascript....**something like *`document.getElementbyId("")`***
or I have to parse it all using String

i don't want to use Jsoup // i don't know but urlconnection is too faster to retrieve html than jsoup *in my case*;in my android app

Answer (score 0):

Use JSoup: it has everything you need

http://jsoup.org

Comment: sorry i didn't mention....i alredy used jsoup but it was too much time consuming for me in my android program while urlconnection did the html retrieval too faster for me....